# How to prevent state reset while navigating between screens? react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

In react native app, I have a home screen and a second screen that the user uses to add items that should be displayed on the home screen. The problem is when I add items in the second screen and go to the home screen I can see the added items but when I go again to the second screen to add other items, it deletes the previously added items.

Any help to explain why this happens and how to handle it?
Thanks in advance
Here's the code of the app.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AddItem" component={AddItem} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

and here's the home screen component

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const { expenseList } = this.props.route.params || '';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Budget:</Text>
        <Button
          title="+"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddItem')}
        />
        <View>
          {expenseList === '' && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddItem')}>
              <Text>Create your first entry</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {expenseList !== '' && (
            <FlatList
              style={styles.listContainer}
              data={expenseList}
              renderItem={(data) => <Text> title={data.item.name} </Text>}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and the second screen

```
class AddItem extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    amount: '',
    expenseList: [],
  };

  submitExpense = (name, amount) => {
    this.setState({
      expenseList: [
        ...this.state.expenseList,
        {
          key: Math.random(),
          name: name,
          amount: amount,
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  deleteExpense = (key) => {
    this.setState({
      expenseList: [
        ...this.state.expenseList.filter((item) => item.key !== key),
      ],
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
          value={this.state.name}
          placeholder="Name"
          keyboardType="default"
        />
        {this.state.name === '' && (
          <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 12, paddingLeft: 12 }}>
            Name is required
          </Text>
        )}
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({ amount })}
          value={this.state.amount}
          placeholder="Amount"
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        {this.state.amount === '' && (
          <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 12, paddingLeft: 12 }}>
            Amount is required
          </Text>
        )}
        
        <Button
          title="Add"
          style={styles.btn}
          onPress={() => {
            if (
              this.state.name.trim() === '' ||
              this.state.amount.trim() === ''
            ) {
              alert('Please Enter the required values.');
            } else {
              this.submitExpense(
                this.state.name,
                this.state.amount
              );
            }
             
          }}
        />
        <Button
        title="Go to Dashboard"
          style={styles.btn}
        onPress = {() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
                expenseList: this.state.expenseList,
              });}}
        />
        <FlatList
          style={styles.listContainer}
          data={this.state.expenseList}
          renderItem={(data) => <Text> title={data.item.name} </Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could send the existing list into the second screen as a navigation param, then add to it and send it back as another nav param. Or raise the state into a React.context and consume it from there.

Comment: @windowsill when I tried to send it back I got the error found in this link https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1- Use Redux:

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

2- Save your state in the [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) and get it wherever you want

3- Pass your state as param in the route:

```
navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to react-native and redux. I tried before to use redux but I am having difficulties understanding and applying it, 
So I guess I will go with  AsyncStorage and search about it.
However, for option 3 how do you mean in the route?

Comment: @MennaMagdy my recommendation is use Redux it's not that complex. how ever  when you're navigating pass your state as param as I mentioned in my answer and get it from props in your second route(you already using it in your code). but I think for you it's better to use AsyncStorage passing param is not a good option because you should pass it back.